# Can we apply same editor template for all columns in the kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Can we apply same editor template for all columns in the kendo grid ?

Comment: Yes. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates

Comment: Yes, If the column type and purpose are same for the grid columns. (e.g. If you want to display a customized date picker for all date column in the grid).

Comment: i have 10 columns, when i enter in to edit mode, only the column 1 is getting dropdown[editor template], remaining all getting textboxes.. not able to load the editor template. please help @Vijai

Comment: Please post your code to check it.